# Gremlin- unable to select 2 variables together when using coalesce

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using gremlin query language with Neptune gdb, and experienced a weird behavior when using select:

Let's say my graph is a single node

```
g.addV("test").property(id,"v1")
```

and I try this query:

```
g.V("v1").as("a")
.V().has("test","name","non-existing-name")
.fold().coalesce(unfold(),V("v1")).as("b")
.select("b")
```

The response is `v[v1]` as expected.
If I do the same with `select("a")` at the end:

```
g.V("v1").as("a")
.V().has("test","name","non-existing-name")
.fold().coalesce(unfold(),V("v1")).as("b")
.select("a")
```

I get the same result, again- as expected.

the weird behavior is when I try to use `select("a","b")` at the end:

```
g.V("v1").as("a")
.V().has("test","name","non-existing-name")
.fold().coalesce(unfold(),V("v1")).as("b")
.select("a","b")
```

For some reason I get an empty response. Any idea why?

(I did find out that replacing the first `as` with `store` works, but I don't understand why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite get the same results as you do for that second traversal and I would not expect to. Here is what I would expect to see:

```
gremlin> g.addV("test").property(id,"v1")
==>v[v1]
gremlin> g.V("v1").as("a").
......1>   V().has("test","name","non-existing-name").
......2>   fold().coalesce(unfold(),V("v1")).as("b").
......3>   select("b")
==>v[v1]
gremlin> g.V("v1").as("a").
......1>   V().has("test","name","non-existing-name").
......2>   fold().coalesce(unfold(),V("v1")).as("b").
......3>   select("a")
gremlin> g.V("v1").as("a").
......1>   V().has("test","name","non-existing-name").
......2>   fold().coalesce(unfold(),V("v1")).as("b").
......3>   select("a","b") 
gremlin>
```

Note that the last two traversal do not return results.

When you `fold()` you lose the path history to "a" so the traversal can't `select()` that step label any more. In general, you can't reference back to step labels that are on the opposite side of a reducing barrier step (like `fold()`). Other examples of reducing barriers would be steps like `sum()`, `max()`, `min()`, etc - where you have a number of traversers that reduce to a single one.

Comment: I checked again and I do get a response for `select("a")`, maybe it has to do with me using Amazon Neptune notebook and not the gremlin console directly?
Anyway- thanks! that explains why changing to `store` solves the problem.